# npm is installed but still showing command not found: npm, command not found: nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, zsh, nvm

I installed nvm using this code `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash`

Then I installed node using `nvm install node`

But after installation when I type `nvm --version` it shows `command not found: nvm` and for `npm` it shows `command not found: npm`

I checked my home directory and also checked for the hidden `.nvm` file and the file is there!

I have installed Homebrew, if that helps.

Comment: I have also installed oh-my-zsh

Comment: Did you put it into your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

```
rm -R ~/.npm ~/.nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
nvm install node
```

Full credits to this lovely lad

If that doesn’t work try restarting your cmd

Comment: not working still

Comment: zsh: command not found: nvm

Comment: can it be problem of zsh and bash